# hadoop 3.3.1 show job history error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobId string : /output_dir is not properly formed

Tags: hadoop3

> hadoop 3.3.1

I have successfully run a program

```
hadoop jar units.jar com.clx.bigdata.ProcessUnits /input_dir /output_dir
```

from the printed message,I get the job id:job_1625033931379_0001
I can get job history list from web page of 'http://localhost:19888/jobhistory'.
[image]

but when I run

```
hadoop job -history /output_dir
```

returns error:

> 2021-06-30 14:54:56,356 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at >/0.0.0.0:8032
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobId string : /output_dir is not properly formed
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobID.forName(JobID.java:156)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.tools.CLI.run(CLI.java:401)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
> at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.main(JobClient.java:1277)